# " Stray '\' in program, 'else' without 'if'

Tags: c

im just learning c and im doing an excersice in which i have to print a 10 x 4 table of numbers within 1-99.99 printing only the numbers greater then 67 then printing the average of each row. however my code wont compile and im not sure why. here is what i have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 100
int main(void)
{
    int r; 
    int c;
    double num;
    double sum;
    int count;
    double avg;
    for(c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            avg = 0;
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            for(r = 1; r< 5; r++)
                {
                    num = (float) N * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
                if (num > 67.0) 
                    count = count + 1;
                    sum = sum + num;
                    printf("%.2f, " num);
                else 
                    printf("%4s");

               }
        if(count = 0)
        continue;
        avg = (sum\count);
        printf("%.2f |", avg);
        printf("\n\n");
      }


}
```

i get the following errors

```
line 24 expected '<' before num 
line 25 else without a previous if statement 
line 31 stray '\' in program 
line 31 expected'>' before count
```

i looked over them but i cant figure them out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to substitute `avg = (sum/count);`.  You should also change to `if(count == 0)`.  And you're missing some curly braces.

SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100

int main(void)
{
    int r; 
    int c;
    double num;
    double sum;
    int count;
    double avg;
    for(c = 0; c < 10; c++)  {
       avg = 0;
       sum = 0;
       count = 0;
       for(r = 1; r< 5; r++)  {
           num = (float) N * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
           if (num > 67.0) {
             count = count + 1;
             sum = sum + num;
             printf("%.2f, ", num);
           }
           else 
             printf("%4s");

        }
        if(count = 0)
           continue;
        avg = (sum/count);
        printf("%.2f |\n\n", avg);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `if` body inside curly braces:

```
if (num > 67.0) {
    count = count + 1;
    sum = sum + num;
    printf("%.2f, " num);
}
else {
    printf("%4s");
}
```

Also change:

```
avg = (sum\count);
```

to:

```
avg = (sum/count);
```

For comparing equality we use `==` not `=`:

```
if(count == 0)
```

Also separate `printf` arguments with a comma:

```
printf("%.2f, ", num);
```

Comment: the curly braces are needed for else? what about the if at the very bottom, i curly brace that too?

Comment: @ZachSantiago Curly braces aren't needed if the `if`/`else`/`for`/`while`/etc. code blocks are only a single statement. However, many people consider it bad practice to not use them in that instance, because it can lead to confusion, and added difficulty if later expanding the particular code block to be multiple statements (in which case curly braces are required to consider the statements inside the given code block).

Comment: @ZachSantiago Curly braces only needed if you have more than one statment, but it's a good practice to keep them even if you have one statment.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run it, but it compiles now, it needed;

1) A `,` on line 24: `printf("%.2f, ", num)`,

2) braces on if, starts on line 21:

```
        if (num > 67.0) {
            count = count + 1;
            sum = sum + num;
            printf("%.2f, ", num);
        }
```

3) division is `/` not `\`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 100
int main(void)
{
    int r; 
    int c;
    double num;
    double sum;
    int count;
    double avg;
    for(c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            avg = 0;
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            for(r = 1; r< 5; r++)
                {
                    num = (float) N * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
                if (num > 67.0) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    sum = sum + num;
                    printf("%.2f, ", num);
                }
                else 
                    printf("%4s");

               }
        if(count = 0)
        continue;
        avg = (sum/count);
        printf("%.2f |", avg);
        printf("\n\n");
      }

}
```